# flatten a Java Object

Tags: java

I have a dummyObject that I need to flatten in Java.
Example

```
public class DummyObject {
     private String name;

     private List<String> phoneNumbers;

     private List<AddressObject> address;
}

public class AddressObject {
    private List<String> freeTexts; // some random things here.. 

    private String houseNumber;

    private String pinCode;

    private List<FamilyMember> familyMembers;  
}

public class FamilyMember {

    private String memberName;

    private String memberConnection;

    private String memberPhoneNumber;
}
```

Now I want to flaten this object and create a list of new object having all entries of these three object. So new Object (lets say it FinalObject) would have all of these 8 entry.

List of finalObject should have all unique entries.

One way to to so is to run 4 loops. Each loop for each lists. This would be very messy. Is there any elegant way to flatten the DummyObject object ?

I am not sure if we can do it using java stream or lambda function .

```
public class FinalObject {
     private String name;
     private String phoneNumbers;
     private String freeTexts; // some random things here.. 
     private String houseNumber;
     private String pinCode; 
     private String memberName;
     private String memberConnection;
     private String memberPhoneNumber;
}
```

Sudo code of what I have in mind is

```
for(phoneNumber : dummyObject.phoneNumbers) {
  for(addr : DummyObject.address) {
     for(freetext : addr.freeTexts) {
        for(familyMember : addr.familyMembers) {
              new FinalObject();
              // fill all fields of FinalObject
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think you will be able to achieve that using stream or lambda.

Comment: There is no way around iterating over each `List`.

Comment: What are you doing with the flattened objects?

Comment: How about writing your "messy" implementation so that we can see what your intended output is? Or failing that, show us a unit test you'd like to pass.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Dynamic generation of object fields - each of which came from child-objects? That will require bytecode instrumentation with frameworks like ASM or javassist and i would'nt recommend it

Comment: @Kayaman , DummyObject is coming from Library A and I need to pass list of flattenObject to Library B. I know it does not make any sense but that's the requirement to support some legacy flow.

Comment: mapping fields from nested fields is possible via mapping frameworks like Dozer : http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/deepmapping.html. As long as your object references are not circular or infinite that may be a possible solution

Comment: It's not clear to me how you want `List<String> freeTexts` to be converted to `String freeTexts`. This is why a testcase you'd like to see pass is vital (or just a sample input and an expected output expressed in JSON or similar)

Comment: Do you need a deep copy?  If no, `FinalObject` could wrap `DummyObject` and provide the appropriate methods.  `FinalObject`would need to keep track of indexes.

Comment: @slim, updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is pretty ugly, but when you need to flatten your object it looks like this:

```
List<FinalObject> finalObjects = new ArrayList<>();
for(String phoneNumber : dummyObject.getPhoneNumbers()) {
  for(AddressObject addressObject : dummyObject.getAddress()) {
    for (String freeText : addressObject.getFreeTexts()) {
      for (FamilyMember familyMember : addressObject.getFamilyMembers()) {
        finalObjects.add(new FinalObject(dummyObject.getName(), phoneNumber, 
          freeText, addressObject.getHouseNumber(), addressObject.getPinCode(), 
          familyMember.getMemberName(), familyMember.getMemberConnection(), 
          familyMember.getMemberPhoneNumber()));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is also possible using `Stream`:

```
List<FinalObject> finalObjects = Stream.of(dummyObject).flatMap(dummyObj -> dummyObj.getPhoneNumbers().stream()
  .flatMap(phoneNumber -> dummyObj.getAddress().stream()
    .flatMap(addressObject -> addressObject.getFreeTexts().stream()
      .flatMap(freeText -> addressObject.getFamilyMembers().stream()
        .map(familyMember -> new FinalObject(dummyObject.getName(), phoneNumber, freeText,
          addressObject.getHouseNumber(), addressObject.getPinCode(), familyMember.getMemberName(),
          familyMember.getMemberConnection(), familyMember.getMemberPhoneNumber()))
      )
    )
  )).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

jan.vogt is on the right track with `flatMap`. Here's a an example that takes two `List<String>` and spits out every possible pair in `String[]`:

```
List<String> one = Arrays.asList("1","2","3");
List<String> two = Arrays.asList("4","5","6");

    List<String[]> = one.stream()
        .flatMap((s) -> two.stream().map((t) -> new String[]{s,t}))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Yours will invariably get nastier because you have to nest a few more flatMaps, but it's conceptually the same. The real trick to this is that each `String` from `one` is actually mapped to a `Stream` over `two`. Then `s` is still in scope to map each element of the `Stream` over `two` to the `String[]`. This produces a nine item list with each pair.

I wrote it pretty quickly and didn't test it, but yours should look something like this (Note that I ignored the private access on the fields in this example):

```
address.stream()
.flatMap((Address addressObject) -> phoneNumbers.stream()
         .flatMap((String phoneNumber) -> address.familyMembers.stream()
                  .flatMap((FamilyMember member) -> freeTexts.stream()
                           .map((String text) -> new FinalObject(/* addressObject, phoneNumber, familyMember, and text are all in scope here */)))))
.collect(Collectors.toSet())
```

Also, for this to work, you will need a meaningful `.equals` and `.hashCode` on FinalObject. Then `Collectors.toSet()` takes care of making everything unique. I'd also consider adding `.equals` and `.hashCode` on your other classes and using `Set` instead of `List` to keep things unique from the start.

Answer (score 0):

I am no Java expert, but I think you're looking for some kind of `flatMap` operation. Maybe Java 8 has it already or it is worth to define it yourself.